# Интеграция python в проект на c++

Tags: python, c++

Ребят, помогите, пожалуйста. Прочитала как использовать питон в проекте. Там написано, что нужно подключить к проекту `Python.h` и все, ни про какую линковку и где раздобыть необходимые библиотеки нет. Может их можно получить из исходников питона, только я не знаю как. Прошу Вашей помощи.

Answer (score 2):

Считаю, Вам, будет полезно почитать:

- [Используем Python в своей программе](http://habrahabr.ru/post/111306/)
- [Embedding Python in Your C Programs](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8497)

Answer (score 0):

Если на Windows:
все .lib и .h идут в одном пакете с самим python. Настваиваем пути в IDE и радуемся.

Если на *nix:
`install python-dev`.
Для упрощения можно посмотреть в сторону [boost::python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/python/doc/) например.