# Как поставить программу, написанную на Python 3, на ОС Windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, установка

Как поставить программу Python 3 на ОС Windows? 
Задача: упростить установку ПО.
Можно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы при запуске инсталлятор сам сетапнул питон и библиотеки? Может, есть какой-то способ, чтоб он взял библиотеки или еще что-то и мог запустить прогу на питоне с библиотеками? Так как возможно, что у юзера уже установлен питон и не было никакого конфликта.

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос. Нужно написать программу установки, которая бы сама ставила питон и библиотеки, или что?

Comment: @overon, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите в сторону [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/). Он создает из скрипта исполняемый файл, который работает, даже если у пользователя не установлен Python.

Comment: Для Python 3 - [cx-freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/). Еще посматриваю в сторону [nuitka](http://nuitka.net/pages/overview.html), но пока толком не пробовал.

Comment: @insolor, заявлено, что py2exe поддерживает Python 3.

Comment: @dzhioev, по вашей ссылке я этого не вижу, хотя, может, не туда смотрю. В downloads на sourceforge вижу максимум для версии 2.7.
____

@dzhioev, хотя вот, есть на pypi.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно посмотреть в эту сторону [Интеграция python в проект на c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/131340/%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-python-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-c)

Answer (score 0):

Существует сторонний модуль для 7-zip, который мало того, что способен создавать sfx-архив, так ещё и выполняет скрипт, прописанный в его настройках. Вот с помощью этого, даже не самого красивого bat/cmd-скрипта можно задать тихую установку python, создание ярлычка для рабочего стола, меню "Пуск", и запустить ваш скрипт. )

В качестве приведения скрипта к исполняемому машинному коду, также есть смысл попробовать Nuitka и Pysthon (генерирует код для LLVM, т.е. платформо-зависимое решение)